# Ruby Array of hashes: Better way to update deeply hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array consisting of hashes in the following form:

```
array = [
          {"id": 1, "items": [{"item_code": 1, "qty": 2},{"item_code": 2, "qty": 2}]},
          {"id": 2, "items": [{"item_code": 3, "qty": 2},{"item_code": 4, "qty": 2}]},
          {"id": 1, "items": [{"item_code": 5, "qty": 2},{"item_code": 6, "qty": 2}]},
          {"id": 2, "items": [{"item_code": 7, "qty": 2},{"item_code": 8, "qty": 2}]}
        ]
```

Do we have any convenient way to merge items according to ids:

Expected output:

```
array = [
          {"id": 1, "items": [
                               {"item_code": 1, "qty": 2},
                               {"item_code": 2, "qty": 2},
                               {"item_code": 5, "qty": 2},
                               {"item_code": 6, "qty": 2}
                             ]
          },
          {"id": 2, "items": [
                               {"item_code": 3, "qty": 2},
                               {"item_code": 4, "qty": 2},
                               {"item_code": 7, "qty": 2},
                               {"item_code": 8, "qty": 2}
                             ]
          }
       ]
```

I tried with group_by, which doesn't satisfy the output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I map the ids, then for each id, I make a hash with two keys: the id and a flattened map of each entry's items:

```
result = array.group_by { |e| e[:id] }.map { |id, entries| {id: id, items: entries.flat_map { |entry| entry[:items] }} }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`group_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) and [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object):

```
ary.group_by { |elem| elem[:id] }.
    each_with_object([]) do |(id, grouped_ary), out|
                           out << { id: id, items: grouped_ary.map { |h| h[:items] }.reduce(:|) }
                         end
 => [{:id=>1, :items=>[{:item_code=>1, :qty=>2},
                       {:item_code=>2, :qty=>2},
                       {:item_code=>5, :qty=>2},
                       {:item_code=>6, :qty=>2}]},
     {:id=>2, :items=>[{:item_code=>3, :qty=>2},
                       {:item_code=>4, :qty=>2}, 
                       {:item_code=>7, :qty=>2},
                       {:item_code=>8, :qty=>2}]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for `group_by`. Go straight with `each_with_object` directly from the scratch.

```
array.
  each_with_object({}) do |hash, acc|
    acc[hash[:id]] ?
      acc[hash[:id]][:items] |= hash[:items] : 
      acc[hash[:id]] = hash
  end.values
#⇒ [{:id=>1, :items=>[{:item_code=>1, :qty=>2},
#                     {:item_code=>2, :qty=>2},
#                     {:item_code=>5, :qty=>2},
#                     {:item_code=>6, :qty=>2}]},
#   {:id=>2, :items=>[{:item_code=>3, :qty=>2},
#                     {:item_code=>4, :qty=>2},
#                     {:item_code=>7, :qty=>2},
#                     {:item_code=>8, :qty=>2}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `group_by` and `transform_values!` (for the latter you need Ruby 2.4.0 and later, otherwise you can use `each_with_object` as @Jagdeep pointed out)

```
array.group_by { |item| item[:id] }
    .transform_values! { |v| v.flat_map { |subitem| subitem[:items] } }
    .map { |(id, items)| Hash["id", id, "items", items] }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:id]=>g[:items]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }.
      map { |k,v| { id: k, items: v } }
  #=> [{:id=>1, :items=>[{:item_code=>1, :qty=>2}, {:item_code=>2, :qty=>2},
  #                      {:item_code=>5, :qty=>2}, {:item_code=>6, :qty=>2}]},
  #    {:id=>2, :items=>[{:item_code=>3, :qty=>2}, {:item_code=>4, :qty=>2},
  #                      {:item_code=>7, :qty=>2}, {:item_code=>8, :qty=>2}]}]
```

The first step is:

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:id]=>g[:items]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {1=>[{:item_code=>1, :qty=>2}, {:item_code=>2, :qty=>2},
  #        {:item_code=>5, :qty=>2}, {:item_code=>6, :qty=>2}],
  #    2=>[{:item_code=>3, :qty=>2}, {:item_code=>4, :qty=>2},
  #        {:item_code=>7, :qty=>2}, {:item_code=>8, :qty=>2}]}
```

This makes use of the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for the definitions of the three block variables.

Alternatively, one could write the following.

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:id]=>g) { |_,o,n|
  o.merge(n) { |k,oo,nn| k == :items ? oo+nn : oo } } }.values
```